# Append retrieving more than requested 13 bytes

Tags: outlook, imap

I'm developing a imap service for our company.

Below messages are the logs of communication between MS Outlook 2016 (Windows 10) and my IMAP server.

```
C:    hj38 APPEND {13}/r/n
S:    + /r/n
C:    한글폴더2
C:     (\Seen \Answered) " 4-Jan-2017 16:42:14 +0900" {14402603}/r/n
```

The issue I have is {13}. The size of next message should be 13 bytes. But it is bigger than I expected... I'm sure it is more than 13 bytes.

```
한글폴더2\r\n(\Seen \Answered) " 4-Jan-2017 16:42:14 +0900" {14402603}\r\n
```

Comment: Are you sure you see `\r\n` after `한글폴더2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`APPEND` takes two mandatory and some optional arguments. In this command there are two optional arguments, so the arguments are, in order:

- the mailbox name, a 13-byte literal
- the list of flags, \seen \answered
- the message date
- the message content, a 14402603-byte literal.

Read page 46 of RFC 3501, and the following pages.

Comment: Thans @arnt . I should've read "2.2.1.  Client Protocol Sender and Server Protocol Receiver" of RFC 3501 carefully.
It's my bug....